# how to read string type (not number) from a text file and store the data in array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

The program will ask the user for the name of the data file they wish to use (full path) and opens the file. It then reads and stores the data in the array? This is how my code looks but it doesn't give any output.

```
int main()
{
    int numofbooks = 0;

    std::string listbooks[25];

    std::ifstream readlib;

    std::cout << "This is a program that shows the title of books in different ways" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    clearlibrary();

    outputlibrary();

    readlibrary(listbooks, numofbooks);

    outputlibrary1(listbooks, numofbooks);

    return 0;
}

void readlibrary(std::string listbooks[], int numofbooks)
{
    const int file1 = 100;

    char readfile1[file1];

    std::cout << "Please enter the file name to read? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> readfile1;
    std::ifstream readlib;
    std::string line;
    readlib.open(readfile1);

    int counter = 0;
    while (getline (readlib, line))
    {
        listbooks[counter] = line; counter++; if (counter>=25) {break;}
    }

    numofbooks = counter;

    readlib.close();
}

void outputlibrary1(std::string listbooks[], int numofbooks)
{
    std::cout << "List of books in your array" << std::endl;

    for (int i = numofbooks -1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        std::cout << listbooks[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void outputReverse(std::string listbooks[], int numofbooks)
{
    std::cout << "List of books in your array in reverse order" << std::endl;

    for(int i = numofbooks - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << listbooks[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = numofbooks -1; i >= 0; i++)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = numofbooks -1; i >= 0; i++)
```

If the user enters a positive number for `numofbooks`, this causes an infinite loop and Undefined Behavior for accessing out of bound addresses.

You need to change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numofbooks; ++i)
```

Comment: @user3081083 Change it to `for (int i = 0; i < numofbooks; ++i)`

Comment: that helped a lot, what about if i want to list the numofbooks in reverse order? i tried to use for (int i = 0; i < numofbooks; --i) but it causes an infinite loop. (for the reverse i mean it line them up from the bottom to top)

Comment: @user3081083 No. The way you had it before was good. `for (int i = numofbooks - 1; i >= 0; --i)`

Comment: yes it works now, i have one more question if you don't mind, finally i have to sort them in alphabetical order. but i am getting error here is my code that follow the one i posted. void sortfun(std::string listBooks[], int numofBooks, int searchValue)
{
    std::cout << "List of books in alphabetical order" << std::endl;
    int index = 0;
    int position = -1;
    bool found = false;
    while (index <numofBooks && !found)
    {
        if (listBooks[index] == searchValue)
        {
            found = true;
            position = index;
        }
        index++;
        
    }
}

Comment: void sortfun(std::string listBooks[], int numofBooks, int searchValue)
{
    std::cout << "List of books in alphabetical order" << std::endl;
    int index = 0;
    int position = -1;
    bool found = false;
    while (index <numofBooks && !found)
    {
        if (listBooks[index] == searchValue)
        {
            found = true;
            position = index;
        }
        index++;
        
    }
}                       i can't post it well because of character limit, this might be better

Comment: @user3081083 I ran your code and it looks like you're trying to compare a string to an integer. Why isn't `searchValue` a `std::string`?

Comment: oh okay yeah i have changed it but it does not give me anything, it stopped saying error but no output, sorry this is my first quarter in college that is why i am having trouble. what do you think it is?

Comment: @user3081083 What is `searchValue` supposed to be used for?

Comment: @user3081083 Here is a working example -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7728f253063f816d

Comment: the searchValue searches for the the alphabet to find in order, so if the searchValue never found, so the position does not move or get updated

Comment: @user3081083 [Or does my original code help?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7728f253063f816d)

Comment: oh great , it sorted it well ,,, thank you so much !!! I wish i can ask you every time i run into problem. thank you

Comment: @user3081083 No problem. Glad I could help! Can you accept my answer too (click the checkmark)? It helps a lot!

Comment: oh okay ,, did i accept it? , it's my first time in this website.

Comment: one more question please ,,,so finally i have to clear the array,       void clearlibrary(std::string listBooks[],int numofBooks)
{
    std::string str;
    str.erase(listBooks);
}                                                                        but it doesn't clear it.

Comment: @user3081083 You can't clear a c-style array. If you used a vector you would be able to do `listBooks.clear()`. Sorry I took so long to reply!

Comment: @user3081083 But you can empty out the *strings* in the array by looping through the array and calling `listBooks[i].clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

`void readlibrary(std::string listbooks[], int numofbooks)` does not return `numofbooks` as expected - use reference instead:

```
void readlibrary(std::string listbooks[], int& numofbooks)
```

You said there is no output. Does it print "List of books in your array" at least?

P.S. This is probably wrong as well (note increment):

```
for (int i = numofbooks -1; i >= 0; i++)
```

Comment: yes it does print "List of books in your array", and it prints only one line from the text out of 25 lines in the text file.

Comment: Well, you get a combination of bugs. `numofbooks`==0 in `outputlibrary1()`, for loop fails at very first iteration due to -1>=0 check. Are you sure it prints one line of data?

Comment: okay its now printing all the lines, but when i try reverse the lines (counts from bottom to top), it is still giving infinite loop.

Comment: @user3081083 Check increment/decrement in for loop